# How many simple graphs are there such that the vertex set is $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ and every vertex has degree $2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If every vertex have degree $2$, I think that it should be simple cycle. So i searched about it, and i found that the number of it is $\displaystyle\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$. I want to know why the formula is this.

Comment: Do you require that the graphs be connected?

Comment: Yep it's connected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed $n!$ permutations, and each cycle corresponds to $2n$ permutations (factor of $2$ for the direction and factor of $n$ for the starting vertex), yielding $$\frac{n!}{2n}=\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$$

But there are also disconnected simple $2$-regular graphs, which are disjoint unions of cycles.